# Changing keyboard layout on Scientific Linux 6.0 and creating new keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, scientific-linux

I have two questions regarding keyboard input and shortcuts:

Is it possible to change the keyboard layout on Scientific Linux 6.0 and how can it be done?

Is it possible to define new keyboard shortcuts so that the terminal can be launched for example, with CTRL+ALT+T ?

Answer (score 1):

Xorg is responsible by the keyboard, so you can set keyboard layout in a xorg conf file like /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf.

There in an example keyboard configuration

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,cz"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
        Option "XkbVariant" ",dvorak"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

On XkbLayout you can set your layout.

And the keyboard shortcut configuration depend on the Desktop Manager you are using, normally there is a place to set this on the configuration section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will have the chance to try it tomorrow. By the way does this procedure require administrator rights? I am asking this because my account is on a terminal machine with no administrator privileges.

Comment: @Vesnog. Yes, it will need administrator privileges.